# App crash on making UITabbar select to nil in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I dont want tab items selected by default. I want them to be selected only when i click on that tab item. So i am making the selected view controller to nil.

```
self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = nil;
```

This is working when the base SDK is set to iOS 5.0 and architecture is armv6.

But the same is crashing app when the base SDK is set to iOS 6.0 and architecture to armv7.

Why does this change from sdk to sdk.

Thanks
jithen

Comment: Without posting some code noone is going to be able to answer your question. However my bet is that some of the methods you are using are not available on iOS 6.0.

Comment: I am making the selected view controller to nil. This line works fine in iOS 5 SDK but not in iOS 6 with armv7 architecture. Pl. let me know if you need further details.

Comment: What do you want to show when the app first starts? One of the content view controllers needs to be shown, and not having its tab highlighted would be confusing. If you're correct about it working in iOS 5, then it changed because Apple wanted to change it -- why, is irrelevant, it is what it is.

Comment: You need to set one controller highlighted for tabbar, one thing you can do is fake it, keep an image or view similar to tabbar at the beginning and when user clicks first time get the place and calculate which controller to highlight and remove the top fake view.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 6 you have to define the root view controller, Please check it if have you passed the nil like

```
[self.window setRootViewController:self.tabBarController.selectedViewController];
```

then it will crash. Please provide further information to solve the problem with crash log.